# Compiling a java file that has reference to another file in another package

Tags: java

I created a file `deleteitems.java` inside the directory `servlet`.

There is a file called `db.java` in the directory '`dao`.

In `deleteitems.java` I imported `db.java` file(`import dao.db`)

This is the directory structure
Classes

```
├───dao
│       db.java
│
└───servlet
        deleteitems.java
```

How to compile in command line I'm inside servlet directory.
It throws me the error package dao does not exist

Comment: You need to either explicitly specify the classpath, or run the compiler from the parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your anser is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15996610).

If you using javac you must set classpath. In the theard that i gave above, janos explins in detail what and how

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have declared package declaration on db.java "package dao;".