# how to solve package does not exist error in java

Tags: java

I am trying to compile my java file name **Test.java**. *Test.java* calling a class *com.api.APIUser.java* which is available in a **user.jar** file. I have added *user.jar* in lib folder. But *Test.java* is unable to pick *APIUser.java*. While I am compiling *Test.java* using `javac` I am getting error

```
"package com.api does not exist".
```

**Test.java**

```
import com.api.APIUser;
 public class Test{
  APIUser ap = new APIUser();
  ap .login();
  public static void main(String[] args){
    //to do
  }

}
```

**APIUser**

```
package com.api
public class APIUser{
  public string login(){
   //to do
   return string;
 }

}
```

If any one have idea why I am getting this error.please suggest me solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make javac find JAR files? (Eclipse can see them)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182465/how-to-make-javac-find-jar-files-eclipse-can-see-them)

Comment: You need to pass the JAR in the CLASSPATH. If you are using Eclipse IDE you can try this,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179024/adding-a-jar-to-an-eclipse-java-library

Comment: thanks subir for reply,But i am not using eclipse ,using command i am doing all the work.so please tell us the solution how to do it using command.

Comment: use javac -cp .;/lib/user.jar -D com.api.Test.java

Comment: @user3090158 You really should start using an IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans. You have several syntax errors in your code, which are easily detectable using an IDE.

Comment: If you are using command line, then you are using some text editor. First Configure it for java extension. few problems will be solved away, next when you compile/run your executable, add respective path to jar

Answer (score 4):

put a semicolon after the package com.api like as below

```
package com.api;
```

clean and build the project and run if any issue inform

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple issues in your code.

1. You have no line termination present for the com.api import in the `APIUser class`;
2. You have a syntax error in your login method.

Below is the improved code:

```
import com.api.APIUser;

public class Test {
    // APIUser ap = new APIUser(); // This call should be in the method body,
    // there is no use to keep it at the class level
    // ap.login(); // This call should be in method body
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TO DO
        APIUser ap = new APIUser();
        ap.login();
    }
}
```

**APIUser**

```
package com.api; // added termination here

public class APIUser {
    //access specifier should be public
    public string login(){
       //to do
       //return string;//return some value from here, since string is not present this will lead to error
         return "string";
     }
}
```

Also be sure that the JAR file is present in the classpath. If you are not using any IDE, you must use the `-cp` switch along with the JAR file path, so that a class can be loaded from there.

You can use the code below to understand how to [compile your class using classpath from command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15996257/compiling-java-files-from-the-command-line-external-libraries-classpath).

```
javac -cp .;/lib/user.jar; -D com.api.Test.java
```