# How can I stop eclipse to modify .classpath automatically

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I check out a java project from svn repository include .classpath and .project files. And I import these codes into eclipse. But the eclipse will modify the content of .classpath file. How can I stop eclipse to do this? just write off build automatically option?

Comment: What's in your `.classpath` file? I normally don't see changes unless the JRE path isn't configured correctly.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't**. But instead of putting a JAR on the Java build path you could 
choose an execution environment which should stay stable when you change 
the JRE and hence the *.classpath* file will not change either.

Answer (score 0):

.Project and .classpath files should not be checked in under svn repos.Blindly copying such files from one machine to another may be risky. These are the files that eclipse automatically constructs for you as per your project structure. If you want to edit, you can do that.

Here is the nice explanation [What's in an Eclipse .classpath/.project file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186676/whats-in-an-eclipse-classpath-project-file)

Comment: This is bad advice for at least the `.project` file, which contains build and nature information. In fact, the Spring tooling for Eclipse can get into a fight with m2e if the `.project` doesn't properly match the `pom.xml`.

Comment: Actually, the Eclipse team has taken a number of careful steps to make committing these and other files to the repository possible and useful.

Answer (score 0):

*Adding information to a 2-year old question just in case of any one else is stumbling across this.*

Due to insufficient detail in the original question, I am guessing that the problem experienced is due to the project's classpath pointing to a different location on the questioner's machine as on the original project author's machine. When a project uses 3rd party libraries (JARs) and is shared between different team members (as hinted at by the use of a version control tool), this is a common occurrence.

1. A solution to this would be to have all team members set up the location of the directory containing all 3rd party JARs to have an identical structure on all individual machines. So instead of changing the classpath, change the directory structure to that required by the classpath.

   Unfortunately this is not always the best solution:

   - Team members may have different operating systems (Windows vs Linux) and you will not be able to have a (absolute) class path that works on all platforms (e.g. `C:\libraries\3rdparty.jar` vs `/opt/libs/3rdparty.jar`)
   - Team members may differ in how they prefer to organize their directory structure. Especially, if a team member places libraries into his home directory (e.g. `C:\User\abcd\libraries\3rdparty.jar` or `/usr/abcd/libs/3rdparty.jar`), another team member will struggle to replicate that directory structure.

Eclipse provides various methods to set up a project so that it can easily be shared between team members. **These however require team members to all agree on the convention, and will be slightly easier if set up by the original project author right from the start.** Two methods most commonly used:

2. Add all third-party libraries to the project itself (the usual convention is to have a `/lib` directory inside the project for this - on the same level as `/src` and `/bin` etc.). The classpath can now be set up to be **relative** to the project's root and thus usable across different setups. A variation for large multi-project-file projects would be to have a separate eclipse project containing the libraries, then add it to other projects as a dependency ("Required projects on the build path" in the "Java Build Path" dialog).

   - This has the benefit of being able to version control your JARs too. However, it may use up a lot of extra storage/bandwith, so may not always be desirable. For instance, I would not do this with Java Enterprise Edition JARs contained in my preferred Application Server distribution, as I may want to migrate my project in future to a new version or another product, without such dependencies - I also do not want to have my project saddled with duplicate JARs that are in any case already available in the AS distribution. So you need to think through your requirements.
3. Eclipse also provides the concept of a *classpath variable*. This may be set up to point to the root of a team member's JAR-containing directory, and be *extended* with subdirectories and filenames inside the classpath. This needs to be done only once, and is also accessed via the  "Java Build Path" dialog.

   - Whenever a new team member uses the project for the first time, he needs to configure eclipse (once) to point that variable to the relevant path on his own machine.

The above mechanisms are explained in more detail on various web pages, here is one reference: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=367962