# Android: Unable to edit project properties

Tags: android, properties

I did the below:

Right click on projetc name -> Properties -> Tried to add a library. I was able to add the library to that list but after clicking OK if I re-open the properties dialog it does not reflect these changes. Anybody come across this problem? I'm using ADT bundle v23.

Thanks

Comment: How you are trying to add library? Add JARs? Add External JARs? Please make clear. One more thing, check your SDK path also.

Answer (score 0):

The properties are saved in the .classpath file in the project folder.
This post may help.

[What's in an Eclipse .classpath/.project file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186676/whats-in-an-eclipse-classpath-project-file)

You may want to use an editor to open the .classpath file to see if the library is added to the file.
If not, most likely you don't have the write access to the file.

Comment: It isn't added. I can manually edit the file so it has write permissions. BTW, its not just about the library, I'm not able to edit the build target too.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are running Eclipse as administrator?