# Eclipse organize imports: how to prefer JRE classes?

Tags: java, eclipse

I heavily use the Eclipse organize imports function but a major annoyance for me is its tendency to add some incredibly niche type from a dependency with the same name as a class from the JRE.

For example, when I declare `Map map;` and run "organize imports", Eclipse may add `import net.some.dependency.of.my.dependency.i.never.use.Map` instead of `import java.util.Map` and then valuable time is lost as I figure out why `map.entrySet()` does not work anymore.

Is there some way of imposing a priority system on imports? For example:

1. JRE classes
2. My own classes
3. my dependencies
4. dependencies of my dependencies (and so on for 5.,6., ...)

I use Eclipse Neon 4.6.0M7.

P.S.: My dependencies are managed with Maven 3.3.9, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: When there are multiple choices for a particular class Eclipse will ask you which one to use, Eclipse doesn't just choose one at random.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about support for priorities, but you could simply say you are not interested in some types or packages in the preference page `Java` / `Appearance` / `Type filters`. Types here are not shown in content assist.

E.g. I never develop in AWT or Swing, so I turn them off for the content assist as can be seen in the screenshot[image: Filtering out AWT and Swing from content assist]

Comment: This helps in many instances but a true priority list would still be even more useful.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a close look at the Eclipse `.classpath` file in the project folder. If classpath entries are ordered in some way, maybe this ordering is also controllable in the IDE option dialogs.

See [What's in an Eclipse .classpath/.project file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186676/whats-in-an-eclipse-classpath-project-file)