# How to run a Github java program?

Tags: java, github, src, lib

Before I begin I'd like to state that I'm a complete rookie when it comes to programming and Github, sorry. Anyways, I downloaded a project from Github and extracted it to my computer. The folder has no readme or any other directions. All it contains is three folders: lib, res, and src. In the lib folder are a couple .jar filed that don't do anything when clicked. The res folder has a .css file. And the src file has a ton of .java files. How do I run this program/project?

Comment: A link to the GH repository helps to answer.

Comment: There's no general way to "run a Github java project" - it really depends on the specifics of the project, how its developer has set it up. Since there's no documentation, you may need to inspect the source code.

Comment: The premise of this question is difficult to follow. A correctly packaged .jar file should run no problem. You haven't told us what the repo is, or why you're trying to run it, and the fact that github is the place you located the files, doesn't really tell us anything about the files you intend to run other than where you got them.

Comment: Are there perhaps any _"dot"_ files or folders, for example `.project` or `.idea`? These may be hidden by your operating system by default.

Comment: Phil, I clicked the box to show hidden items and there is indeed a .project file. What do I do with this?

Comment: See [What's in an Eclipse .classpath/.project file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186676/whats-in-an-eclipse-classpath-project-file). Use an IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse to open the project. You should be able to compile and run it from there

Comment: By the way, those `.jar` files that "don't do anything when clicked" are most likely _libraries_ (i.e. dependencies) used by the code under `src`. Since they're libraries—not applications—they won't have been configured to execute when double-clicked.